# CakePHP DIV option for Dropdowns

Tags: forms, cakephp, html, drop-down-menu, html-helper

It's easy to configure a Div using the form helper for standard input boxes. An example int he manual is...

```
    echo $this->Form->input('User.name', array('div' => 'class_name'));
```

However, I can't achieve the same thing with dropdown menus?

Can anyone help out as to how to wrap a dropdown with a DIV using the form helper method?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I imagine you've been building your dropdowns with `FormHelper::select`, which doesn't include all the sugar of `FormHelper::input`, like automatic `<div />` wrapping, magic error-messages, etc. You can get `FormHelper::input` to output a dropdown using the following.

```
$this->Form->input(
  'User.country', 
  array(
    'options'=>$arrayOfCountries,
    'div'=>'class_name'
  ) 
);
```

The `options` parameter indicates to `FormHelper::input` that you want a dropdown. You could achieve the same effect with the `type` parameter (ie. `'type'=>'select'`), but the `options` parameter gives the same effect while also taking care of preparing the dropdown's options.